# Kendo UI: Auto refresh grid without flickering and closing accordions

Tags: jquery, kendo-grid

I am using Kendo UI in my web application. I have specified `dataSource.transport.read` property to make kendo grid fetch data using XHR request and populate it on web page. The problem is, when I call:

```
$("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();
```

It flickers the screen (displays loading icon until it completes its request). Also, it will close all open accordions (sub-grids), which doesn't give a nice UI experience to the user.

Could anybody please tell me how can I update the data **in-place**, without flickering and closing any open accordions?

Comment: I wonder this too...

Comment: you can call timeout to avoid accordions being closed